# Multiprocessing two functions while sharing data

Tags: python, multithreading, python-2.7, multiprocessing, python-multiprocessing

I just started out with Python so please bear with me.

My code looks something like this right now (simplified)

```
lst = []

def func1():
    while True:
        **doing some stuff with selenium, performing some operations on lst**

        **I never break the loop**

def func2():
    while True:
        **doing some stuff with selenium, performing some operations on lst**
        **I never break the loop**
```

So far so good. However, I need both functions to run simultaneously while also doing stuff to the same list and exchanging them. For example, func1 might append something to lst and func2 might remove something from lst then func1 might remove something etc. Both functions need to run indefinitely, so the infinte loops don't make it any easier.

I read a little about multithreading but from my understanding multithreading doesn't really run parallel, so my code will get executed slower. That's simply not an option. I also read that multithreading and Selenium aren't exactly a match made in heaven.

So, how can I achieve this? I need both functions to be able to perform operations on my list while running simultaneously indefinitely.

I could also use some help on the Multiprocessing stuff. Mapping, pools, queues... I don't even know where to start.

I really need your help guys and I would very much appreciate it.

Additional information (I don't really know if it matters): all of this is being run on a Windows machine using Python 2.7 and Selenium and Chromedriver.

Answer (score 0):

Use a [shared list proxy](https://docs.python.org/2.7/library/multiprocessing.html?highlight=process#multiprocessing.managers.SyncManager.list) and a [lock](https://docs.python.org/2/library/multiprocessing.html#synchronization-between-processes) to sync the `lst` between processes.

Pseudo code:

```
import multiprocessing as mp

def func1(lst, lock):
    while True:
        lock.acquire()
        # **doing some stuff with selenium, performing some operations on lst**
        lock.release()

        # **I never break the loop**

def func2(lst, lock):
    while True:
        lock.acquire()
        # **doing some stuff with selenium, performing some operations on lst**
        lock.release()
        # **I never break the loop**

lst = mp.Manager().list()
lock = mp.Lock()
p1 = mp.Process(target=func1, args=(lst,lock))
p2 = mp.Process(target=func2, args=(lst,lock))
p1.start()
p2.start()
p1.join()
p2.join()
```

Note that the item in `lst` should be a scalar by default, Python uses shadow copy for the sync between processes.

If `lst` contains other types of element such as list or dict or object, you have to reassign it to the `lst` every operation.